# Netbeans print debug value C / C++

Tags: c++, c, debugging, netbeans, printing

I am interested in displaying a struct / class object in a specific way using Netbean's default GDB debugger for C and C++ projects so I can step through the code quicker.  For Java there is an easy way to do this using the "Variable Formatters" section under Tools -> Options -> Misc -> Variable Formatters.  I am looking for something similar for C / C++.  Does this method exist?

EDIT:  To clarify my question, in the debugger variables tag there is a "Value" column.  I wish to represent this as a call from an object, for example `printf("%s", MyObject.getHeight());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Netbeans enough to help you with a macro to do that but there is an easier solution, either:

- let the debugger access a variable (made 'public' instead of private in your C++ class)

or

- add this code in your program: int height = MyObject.getHeight(); so you can display the variable in the debugger.

Things are usually done by simplifying a problem.

Comment: While the second point is a solution, it doesn't help my problem. If there were only one instance of an object I wouldn't mind, but there are hundreds across the entire program and I don't want to modify the source code.  Can you elaborate on the first bullet point?  Can I let the debugger access this variable in a way to always display in that value field?

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for can be accomplished using the Python pretty printing feature of gdb, as explained at the following:

https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty-Printing.html#Pretty-Printing
https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty-Printing-API.html#Pretty-Printing-API

Using the Python pretty printing mechanism, you can control how gdb will present the value of a given type to NetBeans.  I've used this myself to customize the display, in the Variables tab, for my own classes.  It takes a bit of reading and a tiny bit of Python knowledge, but it's wonderfully powerful once you get the hang of it, and definitely worth learning.